# Exclude single module of multi-module project from aggregated report

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I'm calling `mvn site site:stage` goal on multi-module project. One of the modules fails because in the chain of dependencies, which I can't influence, is reference to the http:// plugin repository.

This module is already excluded from site generation:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <skip>true</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

The problem is, that the site plugin on the aggregator wants to include that project nevertheless and fails on `maven-project-info-reports-plugin:3.4.1:dependency-convergence` report. I don't need this module in site because it's no-java-source module (it calls plugin that verifies deployment to the application server).

How to configure reporting in the aggregator to exclude one module from generating aggregated report?

Comment: I do have the same challenge at the moment. I would like to create a site for the child module, but exclude the child module from some aggregate reports. Did you find a solution to your problem? The only solution I can think of currently is to further separate the filesystem structure into "code" and "non-code" projects. The aggregate reports would be specified in the Aggregator POM of the "code" section. But this introduces another level of multi-modules, I would like to avoid, if possible.